# Worker Thread CPU-bound

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, cpu-usage, worker

I have a TCP/IP thread (the main thread) that is listening in a port. When a TCP/IP request comes i spawn a thread to treat the request. If the worker thread is CPU BOUND (imagine a loop from 1 to 1000000 that do nothing) , I cant receive another tcp/ip request.The SO doesnt give a slice time to the listening thread.

How can i solve this problem? Is this a implementation problem? When the tcp/ip packet enters in the tcp/ip stack the SO must give a slice time to the listening thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Which components are you using?

Comment: I using TThread of Delphi standart library.

Comment: If the listener and worker threads has same priority, it's impossible to happen what you are describing - the OS will execute the listener thread and it will be able to accept other requests while the worker is burning your CPU or some core. Make sure you are actually doing the worker job in another thread! Otherwise you'll not call accept() on the listener socket before work finishes. Perhaps you should add some code from the listener thread?

Answer (score 1):

Use WinAPI functions [`SwitchToThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686352.aspx) or [`Sleep(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298.aspx) in the worker thread so that it gives up its time slice to other threads/processes at the system. Or in Delphi, use [`TThread.Yield`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Yield).

Comment: Is this the solution? The programmer is the responsable for create the code inside the thread. So if he does a while(true) loop, i cant receive other TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Does it mean you have no control over what a CPU bound thread does? Too bad if so. Possibly raising priority of your listening thread can help.